# Pivot tables set as false - Erroring out when using variant

Tags: excel, pivot, case, vba

Trying to solve an error message I get when I run specific variations of the below. The below actually works perfectly, which I used from a comment from Sidarth. However, the problem arises after the following:

```
Sub test()
Dim table As PivotTable
Dim PvI As PivotItem

Set table = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
With table.PivotFields("Week")
For Each PvI In .PivotItems
    Select Case PvI.Name
    Case "6", "7"
        PvI.Visible = True

    Case Else
        PvI.Visible = False

    End Select
Next
End With
```

When I try to replace

```
   Case "6", "7"
```

With something like this to try and make the criteria flexible:

```
   Case Cells(2, 10).Value + 1
```

Or

```
   Case "cells(2,10).Value", "Cells(3,10).value"
```

The following line errors out:

```
    PvI.Visible = False
```

With the following error:

"Unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class"

Do you have any idea why when I use multiple cell references, or even add a seemingly circumspect "+1" to the syntax it won't let me set the rest as false. As a side note, it works if I eliminate everything below Case Else, however, that doesn't do me any good, as I want everything hidden besides what the selected criteria. Any thoughts? (much appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

So what I did that worked around this issue is in the cell J2 (referecned by cells(2,10).value
I put my week. Then in J3 (now referecnned as cells(3,10).value I put =j2+1

Then, I used the "TO" keyword in my VB as shown below, and it worked! Pretty sweet. Seems like a pretty bootleg workaround though.

```
    With table.PivotFields("Week")
    For Each PvI In .PivotItems
        Select Case PvI.Name
        Case Cells(2, 10).Value To Cells(3, 10).Value
            PvI.Visible = True
        Case Else
            PvI.Visible = False
        End Select
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `Case Cells(2, 10).Value + 1` didn't work... One thing that comes to my mind is that it happened due to the fact that after setting the *visible* property of some PivotItem you would have no items visible, and you need at least one. Other explanation is that PivotItem's names are strings and the *Case* was a number, but VBA should implicitly convert the data type. I'd still recommend applying the `CStr` function for clarification. Now

```
Case "cells(2,10).Value", "Cells(3,10).value"
```

is just plain wrong, because you are checking the PivotItem value against a **literal** string, not the value of the cell.

By the way, take a look at the following syntax:

```
PI.Visible = (PI.Value = "6" Or PI.Value = "7")
```